# Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Ipub[]' | mongoose - typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

i'm trying to update a schema in my backend app (with node/express/typescript), but when i do .save() it breaks because the type is not like `type` it's `type[]`

And in my app is happening the following error

```
Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Ipub[]'
```

This is the schema

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import { Ipub } from "../helpers/PublicationInterfaces";

const publication = new Schema<Ipub>({
  body: { type: String },

  photo: { type: String },

  creator: {
    name: { required: true, type: String },
    perfil: { type: String },
    identifier: { required: true, type: String }
  },

  likes: [
    {
      identifier: { type: String }
    }
  ],

  comments: [
    {
      body: { type: String },
      name: { type: String },
      perfil: { type: String },
      identifier: { type: String },
      createdAt: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
      likesComments: [
        {
          identifier: { type: String }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  createdAt: { required: true, type: Date, default: new Date() }
});

export default model("Publications", publication);
```

This is schema's interface

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";

// Publication's representation

export interface Ipub extends Document {
  body: string;

  photo: string;

  creator: {
    name: string;
    perfil?: string;
    identifier: string;
  };

  likes?: [
    {
      identifier: string;
    }
  ];

  comments?: [
    {
      body: string;
      name: string;
      perfil: string;
      identifier: string;
      createdAt: Date;
      likesComments: [
        {
          identifier: string;
        }
      ];
    }
  ];

  createdAt: Date;
}
```

And this is where the code breaks, look the line of code where i put await updateSub.save()

```
  // Look for user's publications

  const usersPub: Ipub[] = await Publication.find();

  const updatePub = usersPub.filter(
    (p: Ipub) => p.creator.identifier === specificUser.id
  );

  // update photo

  try {
    if (banner !== "") {
      specificUser.banner = banner;
    } else if (perfil !== "") {
      specificUser.perfil = perfil;
      updatePub.map((pub: Ipub) => (pub.creator.perfil = perfil));
      await updatePub.save();
    }

    await specificUser.save(); 

    return res.json(specificUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ Error: "The API Failed" });
  }
```

It's really weird, it looks like it's because of the Ipub[] type definition, what can i do about it !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you trying to use the `Array.filter` function to get only one element from the `usersPub` array? If yes, then you're not using it correctly, since `Array.filter` returns an array and therefore your `updatePub` is actually an array. The solution for this is to either use `filter` function and get the first element of the array: `const updatePub = usersPub.filter((p: Ipub) => p.creator.identifier === specificUser.id)[0]` or (a better option) use the `Array.find` function instead: `const updatePub = usersPub.find((p: Ipub) => p.creator.identifier === specificUser.id)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i already found a solution for it, but thank you so much for your answer !